# Facebook access token for website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an web app that lets you see your Facebook wall posts and replay/comment on those as a Facebook page not user. The problem i am running into is that i cant find the proper token or validation method to do so.  The functionality i'm looking for is that certain amount of users log into my app and are able to post to Facebook Page wall as that page.  I was trying to do a long term access token thing but it seems to expire too early.  What would be a correct way to do this kind of task?

Comment: Page access tokens do not expire by default if acquired using a long-lived user access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At first Using user access-token you can't send a post or any action as a page.
  If you want to post comment as a page you need to get page access token
- you can get page access token fist you need `manage_pages` right
  .after this you can get particular page access token using `graph
  API` here is a method

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Daccounts
or

```
me?fields=accounts
```

now post every action using this accounts/page accounts access token its now automatically post as a page b'coz you using page access token

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the authorization token, which you must be; that is the best you can do.  Offline_access is not available anymore.  A solution is of course, to refresh the authorization token periodically.  For this to occur, the user needs log into the app again.  You can (and should) refresh it each time they do.